# Searching user from e-mail

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to map my website users to their Facebook account. Since I have their e-mails I would like to know how can I find their Facebook user Id programmatically.

Outlook Social connector does this, so I assume this is possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First you have to ask the user on facebook for permission to there email this can be done by adding "email" to CanvasAuthorizer Perms. all you have to do is a get on "me" and it will be in that return.

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer ();
auth.Perms = "email";    
if( Auth.Authorize() )
{
     var fb = new FacebookClient( Auth.Session.AccessToken );
     dynamic me = fb.Get( "me" );
     string email = me.email;
}
```

Comment: Hi, JC! Thanks for your answer. 
I would like to do this on a background process and for all users. something like:

for each user in db.users
 user.FacebookId = GetFacebookIdFromEmail(user.email);

And what I need is the implementation of the function GetFacebookIdFromEmail.

Comment: the only way this can be done is if the user has a public email address on Facebook. I know how we handle this is when a user first uses the Facebook login we ask if they have an account already and if they say yes we ask for the current login and pair it up.